# How can I pass a value from one form to another form in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am just revising my request with detail code.
I have a main data entry form.  Lets call it form1.  In form1 I have a text field name permit_number and a button get_permit_no.   To get permit numbers I have compare two tables and retrieve all possible numbers in the query.
When I click get_permit_no, form2 will pop up with all possible permit numbers. Form2 is using query as record source.

[image: this is form2]

Then user can select any number by clicking in the check box. Then when user click select permit number button i want to pass that value to form1.permit_number.  For example if user select 79959901,77994803 then i want to pass the whole string to form1.permit_number.

Here is my code.

```
Public Sub CmdInsertPermitno_Click()
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL
    strSQL = "Select permitno from query3 where check =" & -1

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    Dim pno As String
    Dim getpno As String

    getpno = ""

    With rs
        If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst

            While (Not .EOF)
                pno = rs.Fields("[permitno]")
                 .MoveNext
                getpno = getpno & "," & pno

            Wend
        End If
    End With

    Set rs = Nothing
            getpermitno = Right(getpno, Len(getpno) - 1)

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Data Entry", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal, OpenArgs:="getpermitno"

End Sub
```

First I need to go back to form1 as last opening record place.  Then I want to pass the value.

Thanks,
Htet

Comment: You'll have to clarify your design...maybe share some screenshots and your table models if you can. Is there a reason you're not using a multi-valued list box in `form1` for your permit numbers?

Comment: Is checkbox bound to a field? Is this a multi-user db? Simultaneous users will conflict. Does sound like really need a multi-select listbox. Code would loop through listbox selections and build criteria string.

Comment: Read up on global variables